# Why projects work properly without setting classpath environment variable?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classpath

I try to understand what CLASSPATH does for Java and Spring Boot projects. And I see that it is am environment variable and it is used to provide the root of any package hierarchy to java compiler.
But I didn't set this CLASSPATH, it's missing from environment variables and the projects are working properly. I set only the PATH environment variable and I put the location of jdk/bin.

On the other hand, I'm working now at a multimodule Maven project on Intellij, and for example if I try to use the class ObjectMapper in a module where I don't have the dependency it says:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ObjectMapper'

Add library 'Maven com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind.2.13.1' to classpath
```

[image]

And when I click it, it adds the jackson-databind dependency in the pom.xml at this modul.
So in this case it seems that classpath refers to the pom.xml, not an environment variable. Are these different types of classpath? And why my projects are working properly without having the classpath environment variable? Thank you!

Comment: The environment variable CLASSPATH is just one of several ways to specify the classpath of a java application. Other possibilities are the `-cp` argument to the `java` command or an special file in a .jar file. When using build tools like Ant, Maven or Gradle these have specific ways of adding dependencies to a projects classpath too.

Comment: @ThomasKläger thank you for response! Do you want to say that if I have for example a Maven project order-service, inside the JAR of order-service there will be a file with the classpath of this order-service?

Comment: By default maven does not add that entry into the manifest file of the generated jar, but you can instruct it to do so (https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html#manifest, element "addClasspath")

Comment: Ok, but if I don't instruct maven to addClasspath, my project will not have a classpath? I found this BOOT-INF/lib in the MANIFEST/MF. And inside this BOOT-INF/lib are all the JARs used by the project. Isn't it the classpath?

Comment: I've added my reply as an answer. Basically when you write about "the classpath" you usually mean the classpath as defined by the "CLASSPATH" environment variable or as defined by the "-cp" command line argument. Spring Boot brings its own class loading mechanism that loads classes from outside of what you specify with "the classpath" - it is some kind of "spring boot specific class path" that "pure Java" doesn't understand out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE puts 'Maven Dependancies' on the class path.

When a jar is built for deployment Maven puts all the listed dependencies in the jar file it builds. Java knows how to read this info and put the right locations on the classpath.

The locations of jars are listed in the `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.2.2
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.altron.ne.SpringBootApp
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.7.2
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

In this case (Spring Boot application) the dependency jars are all in `BOOT-INF/lib/` within the main jar file.

Comment: This: `Java knows how to read this info and put the right locations on the classpath.` is not correct because the boot-strap loader of Spring Boot(JarLauncher) does this. Not Java itself. That exactly the reason why here:  `Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/`.

Comment: If this answer resolved you question, please accept the answer. If not, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath is a feature of the JVM (actually: the built-in `ClassLoader`s) that allows you to specify where Java (without any extensions) should load classes from: a list of .jar files that contain classes and a list of directories that contain classes.

When you start a Java application with

```
java -jar yourapp.jar
```

the classpath (as defined either through the environment variable "CLASSPATH" or through the command line argument "-cp") is ignored.

Instead of that, Java reads the file "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" and uses two attributes from that file:

- `Class-Path` contains the list of jar files and directories to read class files from
- `Main-Class` contains the name of the class that contains the `public static void main(String... args)` method

Spring Boot is a special case because it brings its own `ClassLoader` implementation that loads additional classes not from Javas classpath.

In a Spring Boot application only the "Main-Class" attribute is set, meaning that only classes directly contained in the jar are on the classpath. Among these classes is a Spring Boot specific `ClassLoader` (the `LaunchedURLClassLoader`) and it is this special ClassLoader the interprets the "Spring-Boot-Classes" and "Spring-Boot-Lib" attributes.

Using this method allows Spring Boot to package all dependencies into a single "yourapp.jar" file - something that Java doesn't support out-of-the-box.